# Duplicate display Issue in an AngularJS drop-down list

Tags: json, angular, duplicates, ng-options

[look this image to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zfgT.png)

I develop a simple application (to start) in AngularJS and I have a worry because my drop down list that allows to choose the list of movies by style, displays the styles present several times in my JSON file. I have tried several solutions but nothing works and I block on it for a while, there is only that (and can be added by after) to finish my application and fill my JSON file.
JSON FILE :

```
[
    {
        "picture" : "la-malediction",
        "title" : "LA MALEDICTION",
        "year" : "1976",
        "time" : "1h41",
        "director" : "Richard Donner",
        "synopsis" : "Robert Thorn est ambassadeur des États-Unis à Londres. Plusieurs décès tragiques et étranges ont lieu dans son entourage. Keith Jennings, un photographe et le père Brennan finissent par convaincre Thorn que Damien, son fils de cinq ans, un orphelin aux origines obscures qu'il a adopté à sa naissance à l'insu de sa femme qui venait de faire une fausse couche, n'est autre que l'Antéchrist.",
        "style" : "Horreur",    
        "scenario" : "David Seltzer",
        "production" : "20th Century Fox",
        "music" : "Jerry Goldsmith",
        "score" : "7.5/10",
        "actors" : "Gregory Peck, Lee Remick, David Warner, Billie Whitelaw, Patrick Throughton, Harvey Stephens, Sheila Reynor, Martin Benson, Leo McKern, Tommy Duggan, Anthony Nicholls, Nicholas Campbell"
    },

    {
        "picture" : "volte-face",
        "title" : "Volte/Face",     
        "year" : "1997",
        "time" : "2h18",
        "director" : "John Woo",
        "synopsis" : "1991 : le terroriste Castor Troy tente d'abattre son ennemi juré Sean Archer, agent du FBI. Au moment du tir, il rate Archer, mais abat accidentellement son fils. Six ans plus tard, Castor est repéré à Los Angeles. À la suite d'un violent affrontement à l'aéroport, Castor est plongé dans le coma par Archer. Ce dernier apprend que Troy a placé une bombe chimique en ville. Il prend le visage de Troy, grâce à une opération chirurgicale, afin d'infiltrer un pénitencier secret où est détenu Pollux, le frère de Castor, pour connaitre l'emplacement de la bombe. Entre-temps, Troy sort du coma et se fait lui-même greffer le masque d'Archer, puis tue tous ceux qui sont au courant de l'opération, volant ainsi le travail, la vie et la femme d'Archer. Livré à lui-même, privé de son identité, ce dernier décide de s'évader...",
        "style" : "Thriller",       
        "scenario" : "Mike Werb, Michael Colleary",
        "production" : "Paramount Picture",
        "music" : "John Powell",
        "score" : "9/10",
        "actors" : "Joh Travolta, Nicolas Cage, Joan Allen, Alessandro Nivola, Dominique Swain, Gina Gershon, Nick Cassavetes"

    },

    {
        "picture" : "la-fureur-du-dragon",
        "title" : "La fureur du dragon",        
        "year" : "1997",
        "time" : "2h18",
        "director" : "John Woo",
        "synopsis" : "1991 : le terroriste Castor Troy tente d'abattre son ennemi juré Sean Archer, agent du FBI. Au moment du tir, il rate Archer, mais abat accidentellement son fils. Six ans plus tard, Castor est repéré à Los Angeles. À la suite d'un violent affrontement à l'aéroport, Castor est plongé dans le coma par Archer. Ce dernier apprend que Troy a placé une bombe chimique en ville. Il prend le visage de Troy, grâce à une opération chirurgicale, afin d'infiltrer un pénitencier secret où est détenu Pollux, le frère de Castor, pour connaitre l'emplacement de la bombe. Entre-temps, Troy sort du coma et se fait lui-même greffer le masque d'Archer, puis tue tous ceux qui sont au courant de l'opération, volant ainsi le travail, la vie et la femme d'Archer. Livré à lui-même, privé de son identité, ce dernier décide de s'évader...",
        "style" : "Kung-fu",        
        "scenario" : "Mike Werb, Michael Colleary",
        "production" : "Paramount Picture",
        "music" : "John Powell",
        "score" : "9/10",
        "actors" : "John Travolta, Nicolas Cage, Joan Allen, Alessandro Nivola, Dominique Swain, Gina Gershon, Nick Cassavetes"

    },

    {
        "picture" : "la-fureur-du-dragon",
        "title" : "La fureur du dragon",        
        "year" : "1997",
        "time" : "2h18",
        "director" : "John Woo",
        "synopsis" : "1991 : le terroriste Castor Troy tente d'abattre son ennemi juré Sean Archer, agent du FBI. Au moment du tir, il rate Archer, mais abat accidentellement son fils. Six ans plus tard, Castor est repéré à Los Angeles. À la suite d'un violent affrontement à l'aéroport, Castor est plongé dans le coma par Archer. Ce dernier apprend que Troy a placé une bombe chimique en ville. Il prend le visage de Troy, grâce à une opération chirurgicale, afin d'infiltrer un pénitencier secret où est détenu Pollux, le frère de Castor, pour connaitre l'emplacement de la bombe. Entre-temps, Troy sort du coma et se fait lui-même greffer le masque d'Archer, puis tue tous ceux qui sont au courant de l'opération, volant ainsi le travail, la vie et la femme d'Archer. Livré à lui-même, privé de son identité, ce dernier décide de s'évader...",
        "style" : "Kung-fu",        
        "scenario" : "Mike Werb, Michael Colleary",
        "production" : "Paramount Picture",
        "music" : "John Powell",
        "score" : "9/10",
        "actors" : "John Travolta, Nicolas Cage, Joan Allen, Alessandro Nivola, Dominique Swain, Gina Gershon, Nick Cassavetes"

    }

]
```

> 

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <input type="text" ng-model="query"/>
    <br>    
    <br>

    <select ng-model="styles" ng-options="media.style for media in medias track by media.style"></select>

    <div class="order">
        <p>
            <label><input type="radio" ng-model="direction" /> Croissant</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label><input type="radio" ng-model="direction" value="reverse" /> Décroissant</label>
        </p>    
    </div>              
</div>

    <article class="media" ng-repeat="media in medias | filter : styles">

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="media">
        <h2 id="title-movie">{{media.title}}</h2>
        <div class="media-left" >   
            <img ng-src="images/{{media.picture}}.png" alt="{{media.title}}" />
        </div>

        <div class="media-body" style="margin-top:15px;">               
            <p class="description">Style : {{media.style}}</p>
            <p class="description">Année : {{media.year}}</p>
            <p class="description">Durée : {{media.time}}</p>
            <p id="infos"><a class="link-info" href="#/detail/{{medias.indexOf(media)}}">Plus d'info</a></p>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[controller ANGULAR JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z2eh.png)

Comment: Please, provide some code about what you are trying to achieve, so we'll be able to help you. Take a look at this link about [how to do a good question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Don't provide code as image. Put it here, so whoever comes to help you can just copy and paste to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I tried your code and I couldn't reproduce your problem, for me everything is working fine, nothing is displaying several times. Please, write a snippet or a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Good afternoon, i know that this code run but it display 2 times the same style defined in the json file, I have more help, please, I have post the code on this link : https://jsfiddle.net/gabriele_cassano/rg7bevbg/5/. It's new for me to post an help, talk me if you can see the code in this link, if not I can send you on an email but you look expert, I need urgenly help. Thank you.

Comment: I ran your code, the only item displaying twice is the last one. But because the third item and the fourth item on JSON are the same. If it's that the case, your problem isn't on your front-end code, but in your back-end code, which is delivering to you the item duplicated.

Comment: Good morning, I know all that it's the reasy why I ask you help because I don't know how modify my back-end to not display duplicate value. All that you tell me I know, I post a picture with the problem, I don't ask you where is the problem but how solve the problem in the Angular code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got your problem. Well, you can use the [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/) filter called *unique*.

I couldn't find the original code, but I found [this fork](https://github.com/glebm/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js).

So, you just need to add the filter:

```
var mediaControllers = angular.module('mediaControllers', []);

/**
 * Filters out all duplicate items from an array by checking the specified key
 * @param [key] {string} the name of the attribute of each object to compare for uniqueness
 if the key is empty, the entire object will be compared
 if the key === false then no filtering will be performed
 * @return {array}
 */
mediaControllers.filter('unique', function () {

  return function (items, filterOn) {

    if (filterOn === false) {
      return items;
    }

    if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
      var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

      var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
        if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
          return item[filterOn];
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      };

      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
          if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!isDuplicate) {
          newItems.push(item);
        }

      });
      items = newItems;
    }
    return items;
  };
});
```

And then, you put the filter on your `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="styles" ng-options="media.style for media in medias | unique: 'style'"></select>
```

I tested it and it's working. I hope it solves your problem.

**UPDATE:**

You should also update the filter to match the selected item *style* instead the selected object.

```
<article class="media" ng-repeat="media in medias | filter : styles.style">
```

Comment: It's working for you? not for me, I have difficult to integrate the fork code angular ui, I don't know where include this code, I send you my code.

Comment: Controller modified :

Comment: It's working but there is another problem, it's display only one mody by style and there is more than 2 movies by style

Comment: Just the style doesn't not duplicate, but that do display all the movies by style selected and now that display just one movie by style

Comment: don't forget this one for the display : <article class="media" ng-repeat="media in medias | filter: style">, maybe it's the problem, but please help me

Comment: I updated the answer. Take a look at the solution now.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, it's perfect, that was simple but i'm a beginner in Angular, but big thank you i can finalise  my application.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Angular is hard at the beginning, but with practice this little things get easier. Could you mark the answer as the correct one, please?